# Entity Framework Seed Method DateTime Error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, datetime

I have a strange error seeding my SQL database. The class code is shown below. I have a syntax error when entering the DateTime value for

> 'EventTime' however; *"Syntax error, ',' expected"*.

This is the correct DateTime value syntax as far as I'm aware, if I enter the same value in to the table directly it works. Does anyone know how I can rectify this, thanks.

```
namespace WLL.Models

{
    public class ProductDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProductContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
        {
            GetEvents().ForEach(e => context.Events.Add(e));

        }

        private static List<Event> GetEvents()
        {
            var events = new List<Event> {
                new Event
                {
                    EventID = 1,
                    EventTime = 15/06/2015 13:45:00,
                    ProductID = 1,

                },

            };

            return events;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var events = new List<Event> {
            new Event
            {
                EventID = 1,
                EventTime = DateTime.ParseExact("15/06/2015 13:45:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",null),
                ProductID = 1,

            },

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of these `DateTime` [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).. The literal you are entering doesn't exist in C#.

Try replacing your `DateTime` with this:

```
    private static List<Event> GetEvents()
    {
        var events = new List<Event> {
            new Event
            {
                EventID = 1,
                EventTime =  new DateTime(2015, 5, 15, 13, 45, 0),
                ProductID = 1,
            },

        };

        return events;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing C# there, not SQL.

Use the DateTime constructor `EventTime = new DateTime(2015, 06, 15, 13, 45, 00)`.